# Nested Soups in Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

To really handle this data properly I'd like to be able to make a nested soup in Python.

So for example in .Net I'd do something like:

```
For Each node As HtmlNode In document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='ClassName']")
For Each SecondNode As HtmlNode In node.SelectNodes(".//span[@class='SecondClassName']")
```

So I can parse through elements in each section I'd already found with BeautifulSoup.

I'm trying something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(WebDriver.page_source, "html5lib")
for EachSection in soup.find_all("tr", {"class" : "ClassName"}):
 soup2 = BeautifulSoup(EachSection, "html5lib")
 print soup2
```

The first part works. I can dump the code for EachSection with a print or get the contents with get_text() but the second part is causing issue.

It throws:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I know I can send the first soup directly towards the Span/SecondClassName but it's reading line breaks where .Net wouldn't and I'd probably have to use some error prone parsing to get everything I need.

Is there a way to do this?

/Edit:

I've been playing around with variations on:

```
if EachSection.parent.name == 'div':
  print EachSection["tr"]
```

Don't even know if I'm looking in the right place here haven't got it working yet. This seems like it would be a neater way to do things though.

Comment: Why does this handle the data properly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I was over complicating this in my head. Don't need to create another soup just another for loop for that section.

This works fine:

```
for EachSection2 in EachSection("span", {"class" : "SecondClassName"}):
```